# NPM always install latest prerelease version

Tags: npm, npm-install, semantic-versioning

I'm currently setting up pre-releases (under the `dev` tag) for a new npm package of mine.

[image]

In my staging environment, I want npm to always install the latest pre-release version of the 2.0.0 version. Therefore, I specified `"<packagename>": ">=2.0.0-dev.0"` in the package.json, but npm somehow always installs the `2.0.0-dev.20180806T153307Z.3eaa718.HEAD`, even if I do a clean install with removed `package-lock.json`. 
According to the [semver-checker](http://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/) my constraint matches the pre-releases published to npm.

Comment: Please do not post images where text is available. Cut and paste the text, not the image.  It's impossible for anybody to grab a copy of your data for testing.

Comment: Because your date/time stamps are alphanumeric, semver requires a lexical, not numerical, sort order. Your choice of prerelease tags is unfortunate. I recommend switching to a YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS.Z format.

Comment: @jwdonahue Sorry for the image, you are right. I don't get the difference between my format and your proposal.

Comment: Numeric fields sort numerically, alphanumeric fields have lexical sort order. Numerically 11 > 0, lexically 0 > 11.  Lexical sort is based on the code point used for the character while numeric sort requires the string is converted to number. Any dotted field that contains non-numeric content is an alphanumeric field. Same goes for any dotted field that starts with a zero, so my suggestion is actually broken as well.  It should be more like Y.M.D.H.M.S.Z.  Read the [semver spec](https://semver.org).

Comment: @jwdonahue Ok now I got this lexical sort. But why does the semver checker and the semver npm package of the semver implementation tell me that newer pre-release versions like `1.0.0-dev.20180809T143945Z.c0a13a1.HEAD` are covered by my constraint?

Comment: The range specification format used by NPM is of their own invention. Semver does not specify any kind of range specification/matching other than how to sort semver strings.  They provide behaviors that are not specified by semver, so you really should take this problem up with them. Have you looked for related bugs in the [NPM issues tracking system](https://npm.community/c/bugs)?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the problem. Because there was no previous non-dev release published to npm for this package, npm always installed the pre-release version connected to the `latest` tag (see the image above in the question). The solution is to simply publish a `fake` release under an older version, e.g. `1.9.9`. Now, a clean `npm install` works like expected.